# Picking a web framework (case inside)

Tags: vaadin

I am building a web application that have several requirements for the client:
1. It should be one page (web app).
2. Contains complex UI elements (that I need to draw/create).
3. Support client side coding (data comes from 3rd parties and needs to be rendered in the browser.

I was leaning toward Vaadin but I'm not sure it is flexible enough for #3.
I don't care too much about the server side, I have a Tomcat server with servlets that provides all the data needed to be rendered (besides the data taken from other server).
I do care about the client side, but have zero knowledge in JavaScript.
My last web client was a complex Flash application, and Vaadin simply seems the "closest" way.

To conclude
 Given this info should I go with a Vaadin (or Wicket) solution?
Or invest time to really learn HTML5/JavaScript/CSS and build my UI in a conventional way?
(with possible help from Backbone/Ember/jQuery and/or any other)

Thanks

Comment: Learn Javascript. You won't survive long without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should get started in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The skills are very transferable and it is easy to get started (although there is lots of depth in these areas, so you'll never stop finding new things).